The problem with getting the result from the previous fragment
In general, I have a fragment responsible for scanning QR (QrScanFragment), it implements sending the result as a string with a numeric value via the Result API.
In another fragment, I do the processing of this result (QrResultFragment) and get it using the same Result API.
getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener(QrScanDestination.REQUEST_KEY, this, new FragmentResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle result) {
                resultQr = QrScanDestination.INSTANCE.getDataIfExist(result);
            }
        });

if (resultQr == null) { 

    Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_qrResultFragment_to_qrScanFragment);
    return;
}

The order of execution of the fragments is as follows:
Processing -> Scanning -> Processing, i.e. in the first case, when there is no result, I use Navigation to transfer the user to QrScanFragment, from there I get the result in QrResultFragment and then process it.
However, for some reason, the result does not come the first time and the QrScanFragment is run the second time.
Can you tell me how I can avoid a second launch, maybe I should change the navigation of the fragments somehow?
I tried replacing the Result API with the Saved State Handler from Navigation, but it's the same.
NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
MutableLiveData<Bundle> liveData = navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry()
        .getSavedStateHandle()
        .getLiveData(QrScanDestination.REQUEST_KEY);
liveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Bundle>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Bundle s) {
        resultQr = QrScanDestination.INSTANCE.getDataIfExist(s);
    }
});

if (resultQr == null)  { 
    Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_qrResultFragment_to_qrScanFragment);
    return;
}

